# A mean square derivative

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm doing an exercise where I have to check some properties about these two stochastical processes:

$X(t)=At+B\;\;$  and  $\;\;Y(t)=\frac{1}{t}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}X(\tau)\;d\tau$, $t>0$.

Where $A$ and $B$ are uncorrelated 2-random variables with $\mathbb{E}[A]=m_A$, $\mathbb{E}[B]=m_B$, $\mathbb{V}[A]=\sigma_A^2$ and $\mathbb{V}[B]=\sigma_B^2$.

I have checked that both verify that are continuous, differentiable and integrable, and I have their correlation functions $\Gamma_X$ and $\Gamma_Y$.

I have checked too using the definition that that $X'(t)=A$.

Now, I need to check that $Y'(t)=A\frac{t}{2}+B$. I have tried using the definition ( that is, checking if $\mathbb{E}[(\frac{Y(t+\epsilon)-Y(t)}{\epsilon}-(A\frac{t}{2}+B))^2]$ goes to zero when $\epsilon$ approaches zero), but i don't know how to manage this...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: where is the stochastic term ?

Comment: Edited. I forgot to say that A and B are rv's.

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman Are you sure that $Y(t) = \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t X(\tau) \, d\tau$? As far as I can see, this would imply $Y'(t) = A/2$. Should it read $Y(t)=\int_0^t X(\tau) \, d\tau$ instead?

Comment: I think $Y(t)=\frac{1}{t}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}X(\tau)\;d\tau$. If $Y(t)=\displaystyle\int_0^t X(\tau) \, d\tau$, we will have $Y'(t)=X(t)$, by the fundamental theorem of calculus...

Comment: Well, the fundamental theorem of calculus applies if you consider the pointwise derivative - but you want to calculate the mean-square derivative.

Comment: I am doubting now. If you consider $Y(t)=\displaystyle\int_0^t X(\tau) \, d\tau$, its ms derivative is $A\frac{t}{2}+B$ ?

Comment: No, it equals $A \cdot t+B$. So in both cases the mean-sqaure derivative coincides with the pointwise derivative (but note that you have to check the $L^2$-convergence; in general pointwise convergence does not imply $L^2$-convergence.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition and the linearity of the integral,

$$\begin{align*} Y(t)(\omega) &= \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t X(\tau)(\omega) \, d\tau = \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t A(\omega) \cdot \tau \, d\tau +\frac{1}{t}  \int_0^t B(\omega) \, d\tau \\ &= A(\omega) \cdot \frac{t}{2} + B(\omega) \end{align*}$$

i.e. $Y$ is of the same form as $X$. You already proved $X'(t)=A$; exactly the same calculation shows $Y'(t) = A/2$.

---

On the other hand, if we consider

$$Y(t) = \int_0^t X(\tau) \, d\tau$$

it's not difficult to show that

$$\frac{Y(t+\varepsilon)-Y(t)}{\varepsilon} = A \frac{2t +\varepsilon}{2} + B$$

using a similar reasoning as above. This implies

$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \frac{Y(t+\varepsilon)-Y(t)}{\varepsilon}- (A \cdot t + B) \right)^2 \right] \stackrel{\varepsilon \to 0}{\to} 0$$

i.e. $Y'(t) = A \cdot t+B=X(t)$.

---

This shows that in both cases the mean-square derivative coincides with the pointwise derivative. Nevertheless, you can not simply apply the fundamental theorem of calculus; you have to check the $L^2$-convergence.

Comment: Thanks saz! One more doubt: I just realized I calculated $Y$'s correlation wrong. Is this the correct formula?
$\Gamma_{Y}(u,v)=\displaystyle\int\int \frac{1}{u}\frac{1}{v}\Gamma_{X}(t,s)\;dt\;ds$ Which integration limits should I take?

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman Yes, should be correct. But using the formula $$Y_t = A \cdot \frac{t}{2}+B$$ should simplify the calculations (since you can use the corresponding calculations for $X$, simply replace $A$ by $A/2$.) Edit: Concerning integration limits: How did you arrive on the formula?

Comment: They gave me as definition, that for a process $X(t)$ defined in   $[a,b]$, if $Y(u)=\int_{a}^{b}f(t,u)X(t)\;dt$ then $\Gamma_{Y}(u,v)=\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}f(t,u)f(s,v)\Gamma_{X}(t,s)\;dt\;ds$

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman Yes... so take a look at the definition of $Y$ (in your exercise), this should tell you how to choose $a$ and $b$. And as already mentioned: This formula is overkill for this particular example.

Comment: Thanks, Saz. I'm writing $\Gamma_Y$ taking into account that $Y_y=At/2+B$ and is easier as you say: almost as repeating $\Gamma_X$. Thanks a lot again!! :)

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong here. Things are not complicated if A and B don't depend on t. If so there is nothing stochastic in the integrals, just come back to integral(at+b) with a and b "real numbers"